# Django cors headers and server error

Tags: django, cors, pip, middleware, django-cors-headers

I'm trying to use django-cors-headers to add CORs to my server, but when I load the page I receive this error on the server.

```
ImproperlyConfigured: Error importing module corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddlewaredjango.middleware.common: "No module named CorsMiddlewaredjango.middleware.common"
```

I've installed the cors-header app using pip:

```
pip install django-cors-headers
```

And my **settings.py** file is configured this way:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'social.apps.django_app.default',
    'corsheaders',
    'dashboard',
)
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware'
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
```

I'm using **python 2.7** version.

Comment: Dear Googler, you may have found this post because of a different issue: Some 500 errors happen earlier than the CORS middleware, so it has no chance to add CORS headers. If the response status code was 500, this might be the issue and CORS might be working fine.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You're missing a comma after `'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware'` in your `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES`.

Add one.

---

Your issue is caused by the fact that Python is concatenating the strings `'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware'` and `'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware'` and is therefore trying to import `commonMiddleware` from `corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddlewaredjango.middleware.common'`.

Comment: Thanks. It was a typo that I couldn't find. Thank you again for your help.

Comment: @Thomas Orozco Can you help me with [ImportError: Module "django.middleware.common" does not define a "CorsMiddleware" attribute/class](https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers/issues/304)