# I keep getting core error in Django as a back-end

Tags: python, django

I'm new with Django, I'm working on a project with Django as back-end and and angular as front-end. I keep having this error while serving Django, please can anyone help me, i tried uninstalling django-cors-headers-3.7.0 and reinstalling it and i still got this error :

````
```


ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddlewaredjango'; 'corsheaders.middleware' is not a package


django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: WSGI application 'djangoAPI.wsgi.application' could not be loaded; Error importing module.
````

**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django giving error ImportError: No module named 'corsheaders'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40387816/django-giving-error-importerror-no-module-named-corsheaders)

Comment: sadly no! i tried it and it did not worked.

Comment: can you provide your `settings.py` file

Comment: check this post also https://stackoverflow.com/a/31277731/14457833

Comment: thank you very much ! i can't believe that this was the problem! thanks!!